# NameError: name 'Actor' is not defined in pgzrun/python

Tags: python

here is my problem - I am trying to re-build **KNIGHT’S QUEST** game based on book "Beginner's Step-by-Step coding course" ([Download the complete Coding Course Resource Pack](https://www.dk.com/uk/information/coding-course-resource-pack/)). And I have got Error message: `NameError: name 'Actor' is not defined`. I also read related one-year old article about the same problem here: [Name 'Actor' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55438239/name-actor-is-not-defined) and added to my code this line: `from pgzero.builtins import Actor, animate, keyboard`, but then I got this error message: `error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized`. The same error occurs even when I try to run original game provided by issuer (I downloaded it without modification). This is my code where error occurs:

```
import pgzrun
..
..
def screen_coords(x, y):
..
def draw_background():
..
def draw_scenery():
..
def setup_game():
    global player
    player = Actor('player', anchor=('left', 'top'))
    for y in range(grid_height):
        square = MAP[y][x]
        if square == 'P':
            player.pos = screen_coords(x, y)
def draw_actors():
    player.draw()

def draw():
    draw_background()
    draw_scenery()
    draw_actors()

setup_game()
pgzrun.go()
```

How should I modify it to get it running? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing the following:

```
from pgzero.builtins import Actor
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved - code somehow runs on Windows machine (Anaconda/Spyder) (it does not run on Ubuntu-Anaconda/Spyder machine), although it runs with issues - when I run it inside Spyder, it gives error message and does not compile, but when I test it and run from Terminal `Python + name of the file.py` it executes well.

Answer (score 0):

I tested KNIGHT’S QUEST.

I added :

```
from pgzero.builtins import  Actor, animate, keys

from pgzero import clock
```

to quest.py flie. Then it works well in spyder editor.

Comment: Please avoid adding multiple answers to a single question, instead, you can always use edit button under the answer to add additional information.